# CasperJS: reference to a DOM element in click event instead of selector

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

I have written a script to perform certain actions on a page using PhantomJS. Now I am trying to write the CasperJS script for the same.

The page I am using is [this](http://www.jabong.com/incult-Tapered-Jeans-In-Indigo-1032119.html?pos=4)

I am trying to click on one of the sizes (34 in this case) and then Click on "Add to Bag" button.

Size 34 is supplied dynamically to the script. Here is how I am doing it in PhantomJS

```js
var point = page.evaluate(function (sizeToSelect){
    var sizes = document.querySelectorAll('.size-desktop li.first.popover-options');
    var filter = Array.prototype.filter;
    var selected = filter.call(sizes, function(size){ return size.textContent == sizeToSelect });
    if(selected && selected.length){
        selected = selected[0].querySelector("span");
        return selected.getBoundingClientRect();
    } else {
        return  { "error": "size not available" }
    }
}, inputElements.size)


if (point) {
    page.sendEvent('click', (point.left + point.width / 2) , point.top + point.height / 2 );
}
```

I am able to find the exact DOM element to click by using a loop in this case. However, CasperJS documentation specifies that the click method expects a query Selector which can be a CSS selector or an XPATH selector. How can I achieve this in CasperJS?

Basically I am looking for XPATH selector or CSS selector for elements based on their content or maybe attributes in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XPath helper utility to produce valid XPath objects that CasperJS understands:

```js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
```

Your code should be functionally equivalent to this:

```js
var sizeToSelect = "34";
casper.thenClick(x("//*[contains(@class,'size-desktop')]//"+
    "li[contains(@class,'first') and contains(@class,'popover-options')]/"+
    "span[contains(text(),'"+sizeToSelect+"')]/"+
    ".."));
```

Note that there is a `/..` at the end in order to move to the parent of the `<span>` element which is an `<a>` element and the one you want to click.

Comment: thanks but isnt there any way I can provide a reference selected element like I did for PhantomJS?

Comment: Well, you can run any PhantomJS in CasperJS. The `page` is available as `casper.page`, but CasperJS provides some abstractions that make doing whatever the hell you want a little constrained. Maybe the [clientutils](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html) module will give you some idea how to combine both approaches. Have fun!

Comment: looks like CasperJS is PhantomJS on steroids... loving it.. sporadic issues I was facing with clicking of mouse on PhantomJS are long gone :-)